# The Certificate Signing Request you entered appears to be invalid

Tags: openssl, phonegap-build, ipa

What i am trying to do here is that i have created an app in phonegap and uploaded on the build but generating IPA requires signing.

i have already generated the Certificate Signing Request via openssl. however when i upload the file to https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ , i get "The Certificate Signing Request you entered appears to be invalid. Make sure that request file uploaded is in the correct format and not empty."

Already spent hours on this. pls help...

Comment: also tried XCA: X Certificate and Key Management too, but no help.. :(

Comment: your CSR file is invalid. How did you create ? . It is created by your mac using keychain access.

Comment: i used the following command on console after installing openssl... openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out CertificationSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -subj "/emailAddress=myemailregisteredwithapple, CN=Name, C=IN"

Answer (score 0):

Create Certification Signing Request like this

[image: Certification Signing Request]

Comment: thanks for the reply... Actually i am using windows pc. Is there any way to create key to be able to generate IPA file on phonegap build..

Comment: yup i am using build.phonegap.com for creating installation files for multiple platforms. but IPA compilation requires key. cann't it be generated using window pc??

Comment: CSR is only generated by your MAC.